# Batch file works when run from command prompt, but not when clicked on

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a simple one-line batch script to map a network drive drive. I'd like to place this in the startup folder so that I have the drive available whenever I turn my computer on.

The file looks like this:

```
@echo off
pushd \\path.to.network\drive
```

When I open up command prompt and run map_drive.bat, it works as intended and I am now able to access my drive. However, when I double click on the file or place it in the startup folder and turn my machine on, nothing happens.

]I've tried running as an administrator, putting the network path in quotes, and adding a "pushd %~dp0" line to the start of the file, but none of these so far have made a difference.

Comment: I am a little lost. Do you want to actually map the drive to a drive letter or open it in a batch file and let it launch so you can run commands in the command window?

Comment: Well I'm stupid. For some reason hadn't realized I could just permanently map the drive. I always run that pushd command when I start coding on the drive and just wanted to automate it. Mapping it was a way better solution. Thank you!

Comment: ok, cool. So then you could delete you question as you have a solution :)